# Null pointer exception in fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-fragmentactivity, navigation-drawer

I have the following code -

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {




// ASYNC TASK VARIABLES
NewsAsyncTask crackerTask = new NewsAsyncTask();
String NEWSURL = "http://acs.bg/Home/About_ACS/News_and_Events/News.aspx";
String ALERTSURL = "http://acs.bg/Home/About_ACS/News_and_Events/Announcements.aspx";
String EVENTSURL = "http://acs.bg/Home/About_ACS/News_and_Events/Events.aspx";
String string1 = "";
String FINALSTRING = "";
// LISTVIEW tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRANgDgM2Zg
private List<NewsItem> myNews = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();


String controlTitle = "";
/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    executeThisShit();

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            controlTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = null;

        if (Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)).equals("1")) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news, container, false);

        /*TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));*/
        } else {

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        }
        return rootView;

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

// CUSTOM MINI CLASSES /////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class NewsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    // Genetics of an AsyncTask:
    // 1. Type of reference(s) passed to doInBackground()
    // 2. Type of reference passed to onProgressUpdate()
    // 3. Type of reference returned by doInBackground(). Value passed to
    // onPostExecute()
    ProgressDialog dialog1;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading",
                "Fetching data from web...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arguments) {
        // extract arguments
        String newsurl = arguments[0];
        //
        Document root = null;

        try {
            root = Jsoup.connect(newsurl).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (root != null) {

            Elements myElements = root.getElementsByClass("news_list")
                    .first().getElementsByTag("table");

            for (Element el : myElements) {
                Element title = el.getElementsByClass("home_title").first();
                Element date = el.getElementsByClass("home_date").first();
                Element link = el.getElementsByClass("news_list_image")
                        .first();
                Element summary = el.getElementsByClass("summary").first();

                populateNewsList(title.text(), summary.text(), date.text(),
                        link.child(0).attr("href"));

            }

            Log.i("ELEMENTS HTML", string1);

        } else {
            string1 = "FAILED TO LOAD";
        }
        return string1;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {
        // super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (string1.equals("FAILED TO LOAD")) {
            /*tv2.setText("Failed to load. Check your internet connection.");*/
            if (dialog1 != null) {
                if (dialog1.isShowing()) {
                    dialog1.dismiss();
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "No web connectivity. Try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        FINALSTRING = string1;
       /* tv2.setText(FINALSTRING); */
        if (dialog1 != null) {
            if (dialog1.isShowing()) {
                dialog1.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }



}

public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsItem> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.newsitem, myNews);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // make sure we have a view to work with in the lines below, may be
        // given null
        View newsItem = convertView;
        if (newsItem == null) {
            newsItem = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.newsitem,
                    parent, false);
        }

        // find the NewsItem we have to work with.
        NewsItem currentNews = myNews.get(position);
        // fill the view.
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) newsItem
                .findViewById(R.id.newsitem_icon);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_icon); // THIS IS GOING
        // TO BE CHANGED
        // SO IT DOESN'T
        // USE THE
        // DRAWABLE
        // Summary
        TextView summaryText = (TextView) newsItem
                .findViewById(R.id.newsitem_summary);
        summaryText.setText(currentNews.getSummary());
        // Date
        TextView dateText = (TextView) newsItem
                .findViewById(R.id.newsitem_date);
        dateText.setText(currentNews.getDate());
        // Title
        TextView titleText = (TextView) newsItem
                .findViewById(R.id.newsitem_title);
        titleText.setText(currentNews.getTitle());
        return newsItem;
    }
}

// CUSTOM METHODS ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private void actionButtonRefreshPressed() {
    if (this.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        new NewsAsyncTask().execute(NEWSURL); // calling NEW asynctask
        populateListView();
        registerClickOnListItem();
        /*container.invalidate(); */
        // because an asynctask
        // can be executed only
        // once.
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "No web connectivity. Try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}

private void populateNewsList(String title, String summary, String date,
                              String link) {
    myNews.add(new NewsItem(title, summary, date, link));

}

private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<NewsItem> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView newslist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newsListView);
    newslist.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void registerClickOnListItem() {
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newsListView);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                                int position, long id) {
            // shows toast with info
            NewsItem clickedNewsItem = myNews.get(position);
            String message = "You clicked position " + position
                    + " Which is " + clickedNewsItem.title;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // .show is important!
            // otherwise it won't show.
        }
    });
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

public void executeThisShit() {
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        crackerTask.execute(NEWSURL);
        populateListView();
        registerClickOnListItem();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "No web connectivity. Try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }


}

}
```

When I try to execute the apllication on my smartphone though, it says that it has encountered a fatal error (java.lang.NullPointerException) at lines 353 - newslist.setAdapter(adapter); , 379 - executeThisShit() method and 72 - invoking the executeThisShit() method. It was previously working when it was in an ordinary activity. I just transferred it to a Fragment Activity and this happened. Why?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you post the layout for activity_main?

Comment: yes, in a couple of hours I will, when I get home :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in    `ListView newslist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newsListView);`
have you checked that newslist is not null?

in toher words in R.layout.activity_main there is a view with newsListView id

Comment: @Skatox , see there are 3 up vote for this answer :)

Comment: @Skatox, it's true but the information of the question is incomplete, normally this kind of errors it's due to that, and this line is the only one who can throw this exception. 

Then the problem is that findById is returning null, if the user writes the layout which is using, then will we see if I'm right or not. But for now, it seems that it was the problem

Comment: Thank you a lot. Will try it when I get home.